# 404 on new posts, after build-time, using Next.js and Sanity.io

Tags: javascript, next.js, http-status-code-404, server-side-rendering, sanity

My goal is to be able to add new posts the CMS(Sanity.io) after build-time, and for the site to be able to display received data on a provided slug using dynamic routes.

Everything works well in dev environment, but in production it seems the page can't use the new slugs provided from the CMS, and responds with a 404.

Here's my code getting the posts from the CMS, inside my [slug].tsx file.

**[slug.tsx]**

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const query = `
  *[_type=='post']{
    _id,
    slug {
      current
    }
  }`

  const posts = await sanityClient.fetch(query)

  const paths = posts.map((post: Post) => ({
    params: {
      slug: post.slug.current,
    },
  }))

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking',
  }
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const query = `
  *[_type=='post' && slug.current == $slug][0]{
    _id,
    publishedAt,
    title,
    description,
    mainImage,
    gallery[0]->{
      title,
      link,
      images,
      display,
    },
    slug,
    body
  }`
  const post = await sanityClient.fetch(query, { slug: params?.slug })

  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  }
}
```

When I add new posts in the CMS I immediately see the thumbnail come up on the website, with the correct image and other data, but when I click the thumbnail I get 404.

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: I had a same issue when using template
https://github.com/sanity-io/nextjs-blog-cms-sanity-v3

If use this tempalte, this issue may be helpful. 
https://github.com/sanity-io/nextjs-blog-cms-sanity-v3/issues/212
Use this template and change fallback setting to "blocking". It works.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty-quick fix: re-deploy your front end code (your *nextjs* app). In my case, I just commit a new change which triggers the building and deployment. And you will see your new page data of the slug.

But I believe there must be a solid solution. I thing it has something to do with 'Incremental Static Regeneration' in NextJS. But even I add `revalidate: 10` to the `getStaticProps()`, it doesn't seem to work. Hope someone else could provide some tips on such issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `getServerSideProps` instead since you want new blog posts in Sanity to show up on your production as soon as it's published and not on every build.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll definitely check this out, when you said it it makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

After also facing this and trying to use `pages/api/revalidate` incremental static regeneration (ISR) with Next13, I've come to the conclusion its not supported and you just have to kick-off a new build :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).